# How to make a drop down menu open horizontally in line with the icon (on the right of the icon)

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, navigation, horizontal-line

I currently have a dropdown menu opening on click of an icon, but I want it to open horizontally now, stretching across from the website. When the burger-menu icon is clicked I want it to open on the right of the icon, and when the account icon is clicked I want the menu to open horizontally to the left.

```js
// JavaScript Document
 $('.burger-menu').click(function(){
  $('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('show');
});
$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.burger-menu').length) {
        if($('.dropdown-content').is(":visible")) {
            $('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('show');
        }
    }        
});

 $('.account').click(function(){
  $('.dropdown-content2').toggleClass('show');
});
$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.account').length) {
        if($('.dropdown-content2').is(":visible")) {
            $('.dropdown-content2').toggleClass('show');
        }
    }        
});
```

```css
.logo {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: -50px;
}
.account {
 display: block;
 margin-left: 1300px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 160px;
 margin-top: -195px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.burger-menu {
 display: block;
 margin-left: 107.5px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 160px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000000;
 margin-left: 90px;
    min-width: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    padding: 30px 16px;
 text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
 font-size: 17px;
 font-family: futura, 'Futura Condensed Medium';
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background-color: #000000;
 color: white;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-content.show {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .burger-menu {
    background-color: #000000;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
 font-size: 25px;
}

.show {
 display:block;
}

.dropdown2 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000000;
 margin-left: 1100px;
    min-width: 250px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content2 a {
    color: white;
    padding: 30px 17px;
 text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
 font-size: 17px;
 font-family: futura, 'Futura Condensed Medium';
}

.dropdown-content2 a:hover {
 background-color: #000000;
 color: white;
}

.dropdown2 .dropdown-content2.show {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown2:hover .account {
    background-color: #000000;
}

.dropdown2 a:hover {
 font-size: 25px;
}

.copyright {
 margin-top: 100px;
 margin-left: 1220px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: futura, 'Futura Condensed Medium';
 color: white;
  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>PS</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 background-color: #000000;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
 <div class="dropdown">
  <input type="image" width="30" height="30" src="images/burger-menu(white).png" class="burger-menu" onmouseover="this.src='images/burger-menu-outline(white).png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/burger-menu(white).png'"/>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="hoodies.html">HOODIES</a>
    <a href="shirts.html">SHIRTS</a>
    <a href="bottoms.html">BOTTOMS</a>
    <a href="accessories.html">ACCESSORIES</a>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="dropdown2">
  <input type="image" width="30" height="30" src="images/account2(white).png" class="account" onmouseover="this.src='images/account-outline(white).png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/account(white).png'"/>
  <div class="dropdown-content2">
    <a href="#">LOGIN / SIGN UP</a>
    <a href="#">CART</a>
  </div>
</div>
 </nav>
 <a></a>
 <img class="logo" src="images/weblogo(white).png" width="700" height="400"/>
 <p class="copyright">© PUBLIC SERVANT 2017</p>

<script src="js/js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have a question which is directly related to any image/icon, please make sure to use full path of that image/icon. We can's see anything in this code snippet. No click event. Please try editing your code and make relevant elements visible.

Comment: It works perfectly... I need to slightly change the code so that the two icons don't drop down menu's vertically, but horizontally instead.